# android Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK doent receive when other app is in background

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a broadcast receiver for every minute from my app's main Activity using Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK. Its works fine when i exit from the app using back key or home key.

But after exiting from my app and starting any other random app...the broadcast receiver stop receiving minute ticks.

PLz help me on this cant find any solution for hours. I want to keep receiving the minute broadcast even when other apps are in foreground.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When your app is in the background, Android may terminate it anytime it sees fit. Usually this happens when there is a need for memory, i.e. when other programs are started.

To keep Android from automatically terminating your app you need a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). Using a services makes it a lot less likely (but not impossible) for Android to kill your process when it needs the memory.